# Using Google App Engine with GoDaddy Domain

Tags: google-app-engine

I set up 301 redirect in my GoDaddy settings. It still hasn't updated and I am getting impatient.

What will happen if I set the DNS A entries to google's servers?

Comment: Why not just point the domain to your app with a CNAME? Then your app will actually serve off that domain, rather than 302ing to your appspot domain.

Comment: I actually did set the A entries to Google's servers. No need for CNAMEs anymore. There were problems because I couldn't use a CNAME to redirect the naked domain to ghs.google.com.

Comment: App Engine doesn't support naked domains, or A records. You need to use CNAMEs.

Comment: What about this? http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2518373

Comment: That's forwarding using Google Apps, which sets up a redirect so `foo.com/bar` gets redirected to `www.foo.com/bar`. I was referring to serving `foo.com/bar` directly. You really, really shouldn't use A records to point your www subdomain to App Engine, because the IPs will change over time.

Comment: Which IPs? Google's IP's? they've listed those 4 IP's since 2008 as I recall. I saw a post from 2008 that referenced those IP's, thought, well... its been 4 years... then I discovered the page I linked to you 5 hours ago and had a "doh!" /facepalm moment. Anyway, seems to work well for the site. (the other solution, posted in the answer below, also worked, but I trust Google's 4 Google Apps IP's more than I trust GoDaddy's IP (64.202.189.170) that the redirect relies on. As I understand it, my A records are pushed on to the DNS nameservers (ns**.domaincontrol.com).

Comment: Are you using those IPs for forwarding with your naked domain, or as A records for your www subdomain? They're fine as the former, and in fact are the only option, but for App Engine app domains, you must use the cname.

Comment: My records have a CNAME for www to go to ghs.google.com. The A records for my naked domain (@) are set to those 4 google IPs. This seems to be the proper way to do it. Thanks for double checking with me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Go Daddy domain forwarding you need to be on the parked nameservers and you need to ensure that you are using the IP 64.202.189.170.  If you are not using this IP for your A record the forward will not work.

Comment: 64.202.189.170 is the IP of the A record. Does it normally take over an hour for that 301 redirect to start working? I don't like depending on this specific GoDaddy server. Why can't I put a few of Google's IP's as my A record?

Comment: I'm stumped then. Is the IP set by GoDaddy? If I try to ping 64.202.189.170 it comes back zilch, and my A record shows 184.168.221.12 which is certainly live... I want to redirect my domain (www.vumondo.com) to app engine (http://vumondo-intro.appspot.com/) -- GoDaddy's 301 ends up showing the app engine domain. How *should* I be setting this CNAME for www? Will it fail using 184.168.221.12? A working example would sure be nice to find.

Answer (score 2):

Google shows that you can re-direct naked urls to a subdomain which is what you need to do.

eg mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com so the user will be able to get to your app no matter what.

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2518373